# Как прервать Flowable RxJava

Tags: android, rxjava, rxandroid

Использую `RxJava2`. Как видно у меня есть `ProgressDialog`, который вызывается и закрывается по завершению выполнение запроса. Как можно прервать выполнение `Flowable` если я закрою `ProgressDialog`

Сам запрос

```
private Flowable<Response<ResponseBody>> FlowableFindPlayer;

  public void OnClick_Ok_Button(final String nickname)
{
    if (!InternetConnection.isOnline(getActivity())) {
        Snackbar.make(parentView, getActivity().getResources().getString(R.string.Error_internet), Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        //MyActivity.this.finish();
    } else {

        final ProgressDialog dialog;
        /**
         * Progress Dialog for User Interaction
         */
        dialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
        dialog.setTitle(getResources().getString(R.string.server));
        dialog.setMessage(getResources().getString(R.string.server_vivod2));
        dialog.show();


        final ApiService api = RetroClient.getApiService(language_cod[Server_spiner.getSelectedItemPosition()]);
        player.setServer(Server_spiner.getSelectedItemPosition());

         FlowableFindPlayer = api.getFindPlayer(nickname, application_id);

        FlowableFindPlayer.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe(new FlowableSubscriber<Response<ResponseBody>>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSubscribe(Subscription s) {
                        //Показать диалог
                        s.request(Long.MAX_VALUE);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onNext(Response<ResponseBody> responseBodyResponse) {
                        //Прилетел ответ
                        try {
                            String url = String.valueOf(responseBodyResponse.raw().request().url());
                            list = responseBodyResponse.body().string();
                            Log.e("URL", url);
                            Log.e("TAG", list);
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(Throwable t) {
                        Snackbar.make(parentView, getActivity().getResources().getString(R.string.Error_internet), Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onComplete() {
                        //Убрать диалог
                        //dialog.dismiss();
                        proverkaNickName(nickname, list, dialog, api);
                    }
                });
    }
}
```

Comment: Попробуйте добавить листнеры (`setOnCancelListener` или `setOnDismissListener`) к диалогу, в котором вызвать `FlowableFindPlayer.OnComplete()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
private Disposable disposable;
```

-

```
disposable = FlowableFindPlayer.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(new FlowableSubscriber<Response<ResponseBody>>() {
                @Override
                public void onSubscribe(Subscription s) {
                    //Показать диалог
                    s.request(Long.MAX_VALUE);
                }

                @Override
                public void onNext(Response<ResponseBody> responseBodyResponse) {
                    //Прилетел ответ
                    try {
                        String url = String.valueOf(responseBodyResponse.raw().request().url());
                        list = responseBodyResponse.body().string();
                        Log.e("URL", url);
                        Log.e("TAG", list);
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(Throwable t) {
                    Snackbar.make(parentView, getActivity().getResources().getString(R.string.Error_internet), Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

                @Override
                public void onComplete() {
                    //Убрать диалог
                    //dialog.dismiss();
                    proverkaNickName(nickname, list, dialog, api);
                }
            });
```

В обработчике:

```
dialog.setOnDismissListener(new DialogInterface.OnDismissListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialogInterface) {
            disposable.dispose();
        }
    });
```